# sys:1: Warning: g_hash_table_foreach: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer, pygtk, glib, python-gstreamer

When I tried the Tobii Pro Glasses SDK demo `video_with_gaze.py`, I came across this warning, and it did not show any result (ideally, it should show the video together with the gaze point). I guess maybe the glib version is not right, but I do not know how to correct it. Here is the demo code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b73399fdbce1d1e3c7c4d32eea82b31a

I use Ubuntu 14.04, and Python 2.7.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Generally that error means a table is being modified from multiple threads. The source you linked doesn't seem directly relevant and it is probably happening within GStreamer. It is a pretty vague issue though it doesn't help that you are using an old and unsupported version of GStreamer and pygtk.

Comment: I install gstreamer0.10, and pygtk by: `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10*` `sudo apt-get install python-gtk*`. I also install gstreamer1.0 by `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0`. But still not work. Use the same installation process on my labmate's computer (Ubuntu14.04), it works. Really don't know to fix it. Thanks.